# Windows 10 freeze on wakeup if any app is open

Tags: windows-10, freeze, wake-up

I have this persistent and annoying issue with my Asus laptop:
Intel I7 7000 2.8 GHz
16 Gb RAM
Windows 10 Pro (updated)

Every time the laptop goes to sleep and an application is open, on wakeup it freeze immediately after the screen shows the Asus logo.
If all app are closed than it wakes up normally.
I have tried many tutorials about setting the power mode and update the drivers and you name it..
No luck for now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled regular Standby mode, or Hybrid mode? Go check that in Power management settings. If it's hybrid, change it back to regular Standby, where the content of the RAM stays there.

Comment: @Didier, it looks like is in Standby mode because the hybrid is off.

Comment: Is there an app in particular that causes the problem?

Comment: @Didier, unfortunately not. Any app would cause the issue.

Comment: One thing you can check: in Device Manager, find an entry called Intel Management Engine Interface in System peripherals/devices, right-click on it then go to Properties -> Power Management, and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn of this device to save power." if it's there.

Comment: Please try running the following in an Admin terminal: `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponnetCleanup` > `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` _(internet required)_ > Reboot if corruption found/fixed, then re-run > `SFC /ScanNow` > Reboot if corruption found /fixed, then re-run

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you. Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.